# Multiple column logic in javascript

Tags: javascript

Does anyone has the logic to display array of data in **multiple** column in java script like

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

and not

1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9

thank you

Comment: Please more details by what you mean with "display".

Comment: @Raynos - Let us consider javascript array i=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], i want to display the data in the page in the formats like shown above

Comment: @Raynos - please note that there is no limit on columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all how you step through the indices.  Looks like you have your indices switched somewhere.

You're ordering by rows.  You need to know how many rows and columns you have.  Then your code will look like this (pseudocode):

```
for i = 0 to numColumns - 1
   for j = 0 to numRows - 1
      print array value at i + (numColumns * j)
   next
   print newline
next
```